# AngularJs "on" event listener receives events sent by "broadcast" out of order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

```
<div container="">
    <div sender="">
        <input type="text" ng-model="text" />
        <button ng-click="submit()">Send</button>
    </div>
    <div receiver="">{{text}}</div>
    <div activity-log="">
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="log in activities">
                {{log.state}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

From above html directive "sender" emits message "1 send" to "container". Which in return broadcasts it. Directive "receiver" listens to this broadcast and emits message "2 ack". "container" broadcasts this message as well. Directive "activity-log" receives both messages. But it receives "2 ack" first then "1 send", even though "container" broadcast "1 send" first then "2 ack".

Why is that? Is it possible to make sure it receives in correct order.

Here is a test link http://jsfiddle.net/wnsg9uzt/. Compare whats on console (events as received by container) vs on screen (events as received by activity-log).

Answer (score 0):

Change Your `ActivityLogController` to listen events on `$rootScope` instead.

```
$rootScope.$on('message', function(event, message) { // was $scope.$on()
    $scope.activities.push(message);
});
```

Comment: This works. but how /why?  In my scenario page will have multiple container with many independent sender receivers (like widgets). So Ideally i would like to limit it $scope. As this will pass messages within container $scope boundary.

Answer (score 0):

If you move the receiver div below the activity-log div, it seems to work as requested. Since the $scopes are at the same hierarchical level I'm guessing angular processes them in DOM order. Using $rootScope would probably be a better option though.

```
<div activity-log="">
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="log in activities">
            {{log.state}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div receiver="">{{text}}</div>
```

Comment: Moving receiver bellow did work. But in my scenario i do't have control over layout. So I think may have to go with $rootScope.